# How to call different api's for different Recycler View items?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have `RecyclerView` with items loaded from using `Call<list<model>>` retrofit. Now I want when I click each of the items of recycler view should load data from different api id's. For example :

1. when I click item 1: should load "http....id=1"
2. when I click item 2: should load "http....id=2"
3. when I click item 3: should load "http....id=3"..and so on

Following is my adapter for loading recycle view items(what should I do here?):

```
public class WhatsAndroidAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WhatsAndroidAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    List<WhatsAndroid.WhatsAndroidModel> WAmdel;
    Context context;

    public WhatsAndroidAdapter(Context context,List<WhatsAndroid.WhatsAndroidModel> employees) {
        this.WAmdel = employees;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.whatsandroid_item , parent, false);

        return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(String.valueOf(position+1)+". ");
        holder.employeeName.setText(WAmdel.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return WAmdel.size();
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView employeeName;
        TextView textView;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            employeeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.WA2);
            textView=view.findViewById(R.id.WA1);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }
    }}
```

WhatsAndoid activity:

```
public class WhatsAndroid extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private WhatsAndroidAdapter WAAdapter;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.whatsandroid_layout);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WhatsAndroid.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
    progressDialog.show();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id. toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    WhatsAndroidApiService service = WhatsAndroidApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(WhatsAndroidApiService.class);
    Call<List<WhatsAndroid.WhatsAndroidModel>> call = service.getWhatsAndroid();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WhatsAndroid.WhatsAndroidModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<WhatsAndroid.WhatsAndroidModel>> call, Response<List<WhatsAndroid.WhatsAndroidModel>> response) {
           progressDialog.dismiss();
            generateDataList(response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<WhatsAndroid.WhatsAndroidModel>> call, Throwable t) {
           progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
}
private void generateDataList(List<WhatsAndroid.WhatsAndroidModel> employeeList) {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.WArecycle);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    WAAdapter = new WhatsAndroidAdapter(getApplicationContext(),employeeList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(WAAdapter);
}
public class WhatsAndroidModel {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() ==android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in here change

```
 public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView employeeName;
        TextView textView;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            employeeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.WA2);
            textView=view.findViewById(R.id.WA1);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);

if(WAmdel.get(getAdapterPosition()==0)
{
 intent.putExtra("url","http://mapi.trycatchtech.com/v1/android_tutorials/single_tutorial?tutorial_id=1");
}
else if(WAmdel.get(getAdapterPosition()==1)
{
 intent.putExtra("url","http://mapi.trycatchtech.com/v1/android_tutorials/single_tutorial?tutorial_id=2");
}



                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }
```

now in your NextActivity get your url like this

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```

Comment: thanks but can you please elaborate by code..I didn't understood ..

Comment: first post your activity or fragment which initiate this adapter , then tell me you want after load each link , that data replace with your current adapter data ?

Comment: sorry I didn't mention ..when click on item it should display data(current api) in next activity

Comment: see edited answer . just add () front of getAdapterPosition , and accept my answer

Comment: just accept my edit request...I don't want display the http  link public

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ExampleService { 

  String BASE_URL = "https://api.demo.com/";

  @GET("Login") //i.e https://api.demo.com/Login? 
  Call<Products> getUserDetails(@Query("email") String emailID, @Query("password") String password)

}
```

It will be called this way. Considering you did the rest of the code already.

```
Call<Results> call = service.getUserDetails("abc@gmail.com", "Password@123");
```

For example when a query is returned, it will look like this.

https://api.demo.com/Login?email=abc@gmail.com&password=Password@123

Comment: thanks but this is not what I want..do you want me add more explanation?